# Ethereum Testnet mobile app wallet

Tags: wallets, testnets, ethereum-wallet-dapp, kovan, mobile-wallet

Is there any Mobile Wallet like Jaxx, but with testnet(like, kovan, ropsten)? Please do suggest me, I am workin on the cryto coin transfer application.

Comment: trustwallet doesn't support any testnet servers

Answer (score 2):

Here's a list of mobile wallets that let you change the network to a testnet (Goerli, Kovan, Rinkeby or Ropsten):

- [MetaMask Mobile](https://metamask.io/) (although you [cannot](https://github.com/MetaMask/metamask-mobile/issues/839) connect to localhost because they only allow https dapps)
- [Rainbow](https://rainbow.me/)
- [Status](https://status.im/)
- [Coinbase Wallet](https://wallet.coinbase.com/)

Answer (score 1):

Coinbase Wallet (https://wallet.coinbase.com/) does support this.
Go to settings -> advanced -> active network
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Sure, you need to know the Trust Wallet https://trustwalletapp.com/ supports ropsten, erc20, rinkebin, etc

Comment: I don't think it is the case anymore, see this issue: https://github.com/TrustWallet/trust-wallet-ios/issues/917

Comment: Yeah as of Nov 2019 the Trust Wallet app on iOS doesn't support changing the network on Ethereum